# HMS Awareness Kit - Single AwarenessBarrier Instance - Multiple day codes or time period

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

We wanted to use single Awareness Barrier instance for multiple day code or time period. But couldn't find the param for passing in the methods , duringTimePeriod(), duringPeriodOfWeek(), inSunriseOrSunsetPeriod()

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your use-case, you can use or(AwarenessBarrier awarenessBarrier) method of AwarenessBarrier class:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/awareness-barrier-awarenessbarrier-0000001050164120-V5

[image]

String timeBarrierLabel = "period of day barrier";

BarrierUpdateRequest.Builder builder = new BarrierUpdateRequest.Builder();

AwarenessBarrier periodOfWeekBarrier1 = TimeBarrier.duringPeriodOfWeek(TimeBarrier.WEDNESDAY_CODE,TimeZone.getDefault(), 9 * oneHourMilliSecond, 20 * oneHourMilliSecond);

AwarenessBarrier periodOfWeekBarrier2 = TimeBarrier.duringPeriodOfWeek(TimeBarrier.WEDNESDAY_CODE||,TimeZone.getDefault(), 9 * oneHourMilliSecond, 20 * oneHourMilliSecond);

BarrierUpdateRequest request = builder.

addBarrier(timeBarrierLabel, AwarenessBarrier.or(periodOfWeekBarrier1,periodOfWeekBarrier2) ,).build();

Answer (score 0):

You can set TimeBarrier per time requirement and add, for example

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    long oneHourMilliSecond = 60 * 60 * 1000L;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.add_timeBarrier_inSunriseOrSunsetPeriod:
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            AwarenessBarrier sunsetBarrier = TimeBarrier.inSunriseOrSunsetPeriod(TimeBarrier.SUNSET_CODE,
                    -oneHourMilliSecond, oneHourMilliSecond);
            Utils.addBarrier(this, IN_SUNRISE_OR_SUNSET_PERIOD_BARRIER_LABEL,
                    sunsetBarrier, mPendingIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.add_timeBarrier_duringPeriodOfDay:
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            AwarenessBarrier periodOfDayBarrier = TimeBarrier.duringPeriodOfDay(TimeZone.getDefault(),
                    11 * oneHourMilliSecond, 12 * oneHourMilliSecond);
            Utils.addBarrier(this, DURING_PERIOD_OF_DAT_BARRIER_LABEL, periodOfDayBarrier,
                    mPendingIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.add_timeBarrier_duringTimePeriod:
            long currentTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long tenSecondsMillis = 10 * 1000L;
            AwarenessBarrier timePeriodBarrier = TimeBarrier.duringTimePeriod(currentTimeStamp,
                    currentTimeStamp + tenSecondsMillis);
            Utils.addBarrier(this, DURING_TIME_PERIOD_BARRIER_LABEL,
                    timePeriodBarrier, mPendingIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.add_timeBarrier_duringPeriodOfWeek:
            AwarenessBarrier periodOfWeekBarrier = TimeBarrier.duringPeriodOfWeek(TimeBarrier.MONDAY_CODE,
                    TimeZone.getDefault(), 9 * oneHourMilliSecond, 10 * oneHourMilliSecond);
            Utils.addBarrier(this, DURING_PERIOD_OF_WEEK_BARRIER_LABEL,
                    periodOfWeekBarrier, mPendingIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.add_timeBarrier_inTimeCategory:
            AwarenessBarrier inTimeCategoryBarrier = TimeBarrier.inTimeCategory(TimeBarrier.TIME_CATEGORY_WEEKEND);
            Utils.addBarrier(this, IN_TIME_CATEGORY_LABEL, inTimeCategoryBarrier, mPendingIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.delete_barrier:
            Utils.deleteBarrier(this, mPendingIntent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


 public static void addBarrier(Context context, final String label, AwarenessBarrier barrier, PendingIntent pendingIntent) {
        BarrierUpdateRequest.Builder builder = new BarrierUpdateRequest.Builder();
        // When the status of the registered barrier changes, pendingIntent is triggered.
        // label is used to uniquely identify the barrier. You can query a barrier by label and delete it.
        BarrierUpdateRequest request = builder.addBarrier(label, barrier, pendingIntent).build();
        Awareness.getBarrierClient(context).updateBarriers(request)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        showToast(context, "add barrier success");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                        showToast(context, "add barrier failed");
                        Log.e(TAG, "add barrier failed", e);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Please refer [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Examples-V5/sample-code-0000001050416423-V5)  for the sample code.